# wxpyton - threads in many modules

Tags: multithreading, wxpython

I'm trying to create simple frame that will run longrun procedure, but will show counting in different window (dialog), but it don't work (staticText1 is not updating)... Here's my code:

Main frame (simple frame with one button)

```
import wx
import time
from threading import Thread
import Dialog1

def create(parent):
    return Frame1(parent)

[wxID_FRAME1, wxID_FRAME1BUTTON1, ] = [wx.NewId() for _init_ctrls in range(2)]

class Frame1(wx.Frame):
def test1(self):
    for i in range(self.delays):
        time.sleep(1)

def _init_ctrls(self, prnt):
    # generated method, don't edit
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, id=wxID_FRAME1, name='', parent=prnt,
          pos=wx.Point(589, 259), size=wx.Size(178, 128),
          style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, title='Frame1')

    self.button1 = wx.Button(id=wxID_FRAME1BUTTON1, label='button1',
          name='button1', parent=self, pos=wx.Point(0, 0), size=wx.Size(178,
          128), style=0)
    self.button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton1Button,
          id=wxID_FRAME1BUTTON1)

def __init__(self, parent):
    self._init_ctrls(parent)
    self.delays = 5
    self.timer = wx.Timer(self)

def OnButton1Button(self, event):
    self.testThread = Thread(target=self.test1)
    self.testThread.start()
    #self.Show(False)
    self.dlg = Dialog1.Dialog1(self)
    self.dlg.ShowModal()                    
    self.button1.Disable()
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.PollThread)
    self.timer.Start(20, oneShot=True)

    event.Skip()
def PollThread(self, event):
    if self.testThread.isAlive():
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.PollThread)
        self.timer.Start(200, oneShot=True)
        self.dlg.staticText1.SetLabel(self.dlg.staticText1.GetLabel()+".")
    else:
        self.button1.Enable()
        self.dlg.Destroy()
```

Dialog (simple dialog with one statictext):

```
import wx

def create(parent):
    return Dialog1(parent)

[wxID_DIALOG1, wxID_DIALOG1STATICTEXT1, ] = [wx.NewId() for _init_ctrls in range(2)]

class Dialog1(wx.Dialog):
def _init_ctrls(self, prnt):
    # generated method, don't edit
    wx.Dialog.__init__(self, id=wxID_DIALOG1, name='', parent=prnt,
          pos=wx.Point(451, 295), size=wx.Size(544, 59),
          style=wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE, title='Dialog1')

    self.staticText1 = wx.StaticText(id=wxID_DIALOG1STATICTEXT1,
          label=u'Please wait', name='staticText1', parent=self,
          pos=wx.Point(56, 24), size=wx.Size(95, 17), style=0)

def __init__(self, parent):
    self._init_ctrls(parent)
```

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail about what you are expecting to happen and what actually happens? Looking at your code, your timer is 20 but your test thread is only 5 so I'd expect your dialog to simply be destroyed

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you posted code that runs.   Don't post separate files, and do include the basic app construction so we don't have to figure out how to run it.  The less work you make us do, the more chance of getting a good answer.